# ClickOnce copy non-referenced dlls to base directory

Tags: c#, clickonce

I have some dll's which are not referenced anywhere, but used directly. The problem is they sit under folder `Libs` in the main project. While publishing as ClickOnce app, it puts them under `Libs` folder and the app dies.

Is there a way to tell on publish to copy them to the base directory where my `.exe` sits?

And of course the `.manifest` file is with the new destination.

Comment: How is the app loading the DLLs when you are not using the ClickOnce, mainly while developing?

Answer (score 0):

1. Right click your project in Visual Studio and select "unload project".
2. Right click and select to edit the csproj file.
3. Before the closing `</Project>` tag add this:

> ```
>   <ItemGroup>
>     <Content Include="$(ProjectDir)Libs\**\*">
>       <Link>%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)</Link>
>       <Visible>false</Visible>
>     </Content>
>   </ItemGroup>
> ```

4. go to file properties change the Build Action from content to None